# Pagination Broken on Loop using ACF

Tags: pagination, advanced-custom-fields, paginate-links

http://dthudson.com/ccr/archive-issues/

The paginated pages are being populated by the content as you can see at the bottom (beneath the posts) but when you click on '2' for instance it loads page 2 but it shows the exact same posts. I want to point out that I am using Advanced Custom Fields to retrieve content from the post-type 'issues', I wonder if this is contributing to the problem. Also - I copied the pagination code from my index page and search page and each of those works fine. Any ideas?

```
<!-- BEGIN LOOP -->         

<?php 

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'issues',
        'posts_per_page' => '9',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>

            <div class="loop four columns hover-issue">
                <div class="column-nest">
                    <a class="hover-color" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h5 class="staff-title big-top-space"><?php the_field('release_season'); ?> <?php the_field('release_year'); ?></h5>
                    <h6 class="staff-name  bottom-space"><?php the_field('issue_number_full_length'); ?></h6></a>               
                </div> <!-- column-nest -->
                <figure class="staff-photo-border">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img class="column-nest image-width" src="<?php the_field('issue_image_cropped'); ?>" alt="photo of issue <?php the_field('issue_number'); ?>" /></a>
                </figure> <!-- staff-photo-border -->
            </div> <!-- loop four columns -->


<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div> <!-- looper twelve columns -->

                    <nav class="pagination">

                        <?php

                        $total_pages = $my_query->max_num_pages;  

                        if ($total_pages > 1){  

                          $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));  

                          echo paginate_links(array(  
                              'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
                              'format' => 'page/%#%',  
                              'current' => $current_page,  
                              'total' => $total_pages, 
                              'prev_next'    => False,
                              'type' => 'list', 
                            ));  
                        }  
                        ?>

       </nav><!--end pagination-->
```

Comment: you don't pass a [`paged` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) to your query.

Comment: @milo hi thanks for the tip - I read through the documentation and I'm still struggling with where to go with this. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your query displays the first 9 posts regardless of page because you don't set the page number in your query arguments.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'issues',
    'posts_per_page' => '9',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
```